# Update from temp table not working inside of SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have an unbound access interface that packages a table from a form up into XML and sends it to a stored procedure on a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

The XML that is getting sent looks like this:

```
<maps>
  <map>
    <gmapId>1396</gmapId>
    <citation>Gray, Carlyle; Shepps, V.C.; Conlin, R.R.; Hoskins, D.M.; Shaffner, M.N.; Socolow, A.A.; McLaughlin, D.B.; Geyer, A.R.; Cate, A.S.; Lytle, W.S.; Bergsten, J.M.; Miller, J.T.; Wood, G.H., Jr.; Arndt, H.H.; Kehn, T.M., 1960, Geologic map of Pennsylvania (1960), Pennsylvania Geological Survey, Map, 1:250000 scale</citation>
    <use>no</use>
  </map>
</maps>
```

Often with several (>100) map elements.

In my stored procedure, I have some code that unboxes the xml into a temp table and then uses that temp table information to update a couple of tables in the database.

That code looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.#mapsXref (npsUnitCode, gmapIdF, useForThisPark, citation)
        SELECT @unitCode As npsUnitCode, 
            T.item.value('gmapId[1]','INT') As gmapIdF,
            T.item.value('use[1]','VARCHAR(10)') As useForThisPark ,
            T.item.value('citation[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') As citation
            FROM @mapsList.nodes('maps/map') AS T(item)
```

I can verify that the XML gets packaged fine, comes across with the right information, and the temp table gets filled correctly by using an audit table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.mapsXrefAudit(npsUnitCode, gmapIdF, useForThisPark, citation)
SELECT npsUnitCode, gmapIdF, useForThisPark, citation from dbo.#mapsXref
```

That just catches whatever is going into the temp table and allows to verify the transmission of data to the server and proper unpacking of the XML string.

The first update works:

```
UPDATE map.XREF_GMAP_ID_TRANSLATIONS 
        SET useForThisPark = t.useForThisPark
        FROM map.XREF_GMAP_ID_TRANSLATIONS x INNER JOIN dbo.#mapsXref t 
            ON x.gmapIdF = t.gmapIdF WHERE x.npsUnitCode = t.npsUnitCode
```

But then when the stored procedure uses the temp table to update another table:

```
UPDATE map.TBL_GMAPS
        SET reference = t.citation
        FROM  dbo.#mapsXref t INNER JOIN map.TBL_GMAPS g
            ON g.gmapId = t.gmapIdF
```

The updates don't show up in `map.TBL_GMAPS`.

It had worked for a couple of years on another SQL Server 2008 R2 instance (I'm currently trying to get the old build # from our DBA. I'll update with that info if I can get it).

A few weeks ago, we had a server fiasco and the database was migrated to a new server running build 10.50.4000. I ended up having to re-set  a bunch of object-level permissions because various parts of the aforementioned access application would throw errors regarding permissions but I don't seem to be getting any of those problems now. I have the whole bit wrapped into a transaction that will roll back and generate an error message if something goes wrong. But I get no errors on commit.

I've mentioned most parts of the stored procedure besides the parameters and the transaction code. The full version is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5536290

Does anyone know why update won't take on my `map.TBL_GMAPS` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out. Someone (me) had defined an trigger on TBL_GMAPS a few years back to automatically generate USGS-style citations upon INSERT. Whenever the code in the question would update the table, the trigger would then fire and re-set the citation. To fix it, I used the solution here -- [Disabling a Trigger for a Specific SQL Statement or Session.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1591/disabling-a-trigger-for-a-specific-sql-statement-or-session/)

I changed my UPDATE section above to:

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x555555
UPDATE map.TBL_GMAPS
        SET reference = t.citation
        FROM  dbo.#mapsXref t INNER JOIN map.TBL_GMAPS g
            ON g.gmapId = t.gmapIdF
```

And then in the trigger, checked CONTEXT_INFO to see if it was set

```
DECLARE @Cinfo VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @Cinfo = CONTEXT_INFO()
If @Cinfo = 0x555555
  RETURN

UPDATE map.TBL_GMAPS SET
reference=dbo.createUsgsCitation(m.gmapId)
FROM inserted i INNER JOIN  map.TBL_GMAPS m
ON m.gmapId = i.gmapId
```

That fixed my issue.